# c++ replace spaces with 2 stars

Tags: c++, string, replace

I am trying to make a C++ program which replaces all the spaces in the string with 2 stars.  On compiling, the program doesn't show any output because I believe the null character is being overwritten or something, as said by my computer teacher.But despite repeated dry-running and tweaks in that nested for loop in the function, I can't find what is going wrong. What exactly is causing this problem??

```
 //program to replace every space in string with 2 stars   
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<cstring>
 #include<cstdlib>
 using namespace std;
 void convert(char str[]);
 int main()
 {
   system("cls");
   char string[50];
   cout<<"Enter a string "<<endl;
   gets(string);
   convert(string);
   cin.get();
   return 0;
  }
  void convert(char str[])
   {
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
     {
        if(str[i]==' ')
           {
              for(j=strlen(str); j>i; j--)
                 {
                    str[j]=str[j+1];
                    str[i]='*';
                    str[i+1]='*';
                 }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is "C with std::cout", not C++. Use `std::string` for a start. This will simplify your replace task drastically.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
str[j] = str[j+1];
```

which moves characters closer to the beginning with

```
str[j+1] = str[j];
```

which moves them further away. Move the two lines that follow out of the loop.

You have other things to fix, too:

- I am assuming that you are prohibited from using `string`. If this is not so, use `std::string` instead of C strings
- Use `fgets(string,sizeof(string), cin)` instead of inherently unsafe `gets`
- You can improve the speed of your algorithm by counting spaces once, and then doing the expansion starting from the back of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason why there is no output is because there is no `cout << string` in the code. Even if there were there would be errors.

Istead of `str[j]=str[j+1];` there should be `str[j+1]=str[j];`. `str[j+1]` is not even set for `j==strlen(str)`.

Also, setting chars to asterisks must be done after the inner loop, so that first character after space is not overwritten with asterisk, so that it can be moved.

Also, if you can use `std::string` then it's better and easier to use that. You wouldn't need inner loop, just one call to `std::string::replace()`.

Here's the code:

```
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        for (j = strlen(str); j>i; j--)
        {
            str[j+1] = str[j];
        }
        str[i] = '*';
        str[i+1] = '*';
    }
```

Comment: Despite the corrections, it is still not working out..@dasblinkenlight //gets  changed to cin.getline(str,50);                                                                                        if(str[i]==' ')
             {
             for(j=strlen(str); j>i; j--)
               {
                str[j+1]=str[j];
                str[i]='*';
                str[i+1]='*';
                 }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will assume that this is homework and you must not use `std::string`. If you can use `std::string`, forget about everything and refrain from using dynamically allocated C-style strings!

---

Here we go. If you want to replace *one* character (a space) with *two* characters (two stars), then your output string becomes **larger**.

```
"hello there, world!"   = 19 characters
"hello**there,**world!" = 21 characters
```

I doubt that overwriting the character following each space with a star conforms to the requirements of this exercise:

```
"hello**here,**orld!" = 19 characters, but seems to be wrong
```

You have space for 49 characters, but what if you enter, say, a string with 45 non-spaces and 5 spaces? The result would consist of 55 characters. More generally speaking: **Who says the resulting string will fit in the old array?**

The easiest way to overcome this problem and arrive at a satisfactory solution is to first *count* the number of spaces, then *allocate a new string*, then *copy* the characters.

Here is an example. I left your original way of receiving user input, and a few other problems with the code, intact, even though it could use a few further improvements. This is *not* C++ code you would use in production! I also used `malloc` and `free` to conform to the general C-style of your code (in fact, this may really be a C exercise!). Take it strictly as a learning exercise:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int new_size(char str[]);
char* convert(char str[], int new_size);

int main()
{
char string[50];
cout<<"Enter a string "<<endl;
gets(string);
int new_size_with_stars = new_size(string);
char* new_string = convert(string, new_size_with_stars);

printf("result: %s\n", new_string);

free(new_string);

return 0;
}

int new_size(char str[])
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
      if (str[i] == ' ')
      {
        ++result;
      }
      ++result;
    }
    return result;
}

char* convert(char str[], int new_size)
{
  char* new_str = (char*) malloc(new_size + 1);
  for(int old_str_index = 0, new_str_index = 0; str[old_str_index] != '\0'; ++old_str_index, ++new_str_index)
  {
    if (str[old_str_index]==' ')
    {
      new_str[new_str_index] = '*';
      new_str[new_str_index + 1] = '*';
      ++new_str_index;
    }
    else
    {
      new_str[new_str_index] = str[old_str_index];
    }   
  }
  new_str[new_size] = '\0';
  return new_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `gets()`, it's a deprecated function and considered to be dangerous. And if you are in C++ there's no need to use `cstring`, C++ has better solution for that. I do this type of thing this way:

```
    //program to replace every space in string with 2 stars   
     #include<iostream>
     #include<string>
     using namespace std;


     string convert(string str) {
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = str.find(" ", pos)) != string::npos) {
             str.replace(pos, 1, "*");
             pos += 1;
        }
        return str;
    }


     int main()
     {
       system("cls");
       string str;
       cout<<"Enter a string "<<endl;
       getline(cin,str);
       cout<<convert(str);
       cin.get();
       return 0;
      }
```

But if you insist to use `cstring`,then modified code from yours:

```
//program to replace every space in string with 2 stars   
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<cstring>
 #include<cstdlib>
 using namespace std;
 void convert(char str[]);
 int main()
 {
   system("cls");
   char string[50];
   cout<<"Enter a string "<<endl;
   cin.getline(string,sizeof(string));
   convert(string);
   cout<<string;
   cin.get();
   return 0;
  }
  void convert(char str[])
   {
     int i, j;
     for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
     {
        if(str[i]==' ')
           {
              for(j=strlen(str); j>i; j--)
                 {
                    str[j+1]=str[j];
                    str[i]='*';
                    str[i+1]='*';
                 }
           }
        }
    }
```

At least you shouldn't use gets(). Though it will work for that too...